# Add "Request read receipt" to Outlook 2013/2016 ribbon (toolbar)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Office 2013 you can reply "in-line". Meaning, you don't have to open a new window with the email.

If you chose drafting the email in a new windows then you have the option in the tab "Options". And you can also add it to the QAT (Quick access toolbar). That's ok!

However, if you are replying in-line the new tab "Compose tools/Message" will open, and there you will have to go to "Tags" and activate it from there whenever you want. I created a new group in that "Compose tools/Message" but the option "Request read receipt" is not available in "All commands".

Do you know any workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to use the VBA macro like this:

```vb
Sub RequestReadReceipt()
    Set objItem = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        objItem.ReadReceiptRequested = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can put a button that runs this macro in your Ribbon group.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to create a checkbox so you know it's active or not?

Comment: Possible, but not easy. By writing Outlook add-in only.

Comment: That's really a missing feature and still the same in Outlook 2016. Very annoying. But thanks for this workaround. It works :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little extension to @thims workaround. Instead of just setting the read receipt value, it toggles it and displays the status for 1 second in the *subject line*. I couldn't find a better way, suggestions welcome :)

```vb
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

' toggle ReadReceiptRequested for ActiveInlineResponse
Sub RequestReadReceipt()
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
    If Not oMail Is Nothing Then
        oMail.ReadReceiptRequested = Not oMail.ReadReceiptRequested
        TempSubject = oMail.Subject
        oMail.Subject = "ReadReceiptRequested: " & oMail.ReadReceiptRequested
        DoEvents
        Sleep 1000
        oMail.Subject = TempSubject
    End If
End Sub
```

Tested with Outlook 2016. Hints: open Visual Basic from the developer options and paste the code into ThisOutlookSession. Create a new group in "Compose tools/Message" and add this macro...

It's not so nice that Outlook hangs during the display period, but this makes sure you don't send the email with that abused subject :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the "Message Options" button in a new group in the "Message" toolbar under "Compose Tools".

This is what I did in my Outlook 2016:
- Go to "Customize the Ribbon" and choose "Tool tabs" on the right.
- Then expand "Message" under "Compose Tools" (there are two of these, I did it for both) and add a new group.
- On the left select "All commands" and select "Message options", and add this button to the new group.

Now when writing an in-line message, click on the "Message Options" button in the ribbon and select "Ask for read receipt".